# How do I replace a door hinge with no screws?

Tags: repair, doors

Any ideas on how I can remove this ugly looking hinge that snapped. One end of the hinge has no screws and is soldered onto the door. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

**`EDIT:`**

Ok, I followed @Chris Cudmore 's suggestion and found the same hinge. However as shown in the photo the broken part is completely rusted, what would be the easiest way to slide this out, would WD-40 suffice ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take pictures and measurements.  (Measure EVERYTHING on the hinge - height/diameter of pin in particular.)

You should be able to find the identical hinge with a bit of effort.  Replace the part attached to the wood, and you should be able to drop the welded portion into it.  Yes, you'll have to throw out the upper part of the new hinge, but it's the easiest fix and will restore the gate.

Comment: What's that rusted dot on the hinge? is that a set screw?  Could it be drilled out?  Obviously this is a bit more difficult than originally thought -- This angle of photography changes things.

Comment: At this point, we're ONLY trying to avoid welding.  It might be the better solution now.

Comment: The rusted dot is not a screw it is just a hole in that section of the hinge, not sure the purpose of it. I was thinking to apply WD-40 through this hole, it would probably seep down into the hinge and loosen it up slightly and i can slide the broken part down by hammering it. Would you suggest otherwise ?

Answer (score 6):

That hinge is welded on. The only way to remove it is to take a grinder with a carbide wheel to the welds, then An abrasive disk to clean it up and smooth the metal frame.  You will then have to drill pilot holes for the new hinges.

Comment: If appearance isn't a concern you could leave it inplace and mount a new hinge above or below the original.

Comment: Thanks @mikes I think i might try your way first. Thanks for posting.